# How to execute code after all the threads finished execution?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, java.util.concurrent

```
private void processEvents(List<Object> events) {

        CompletableFuture<Void> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.runAsync(
                () -> processEventsAsynchronously(events));
        while (!completableFuture.isDone() || completableFuture.isCancelled() || completableFuture.isCompletedExceptionally()) {
            // waiting for all threads to get processed
        }

        if (completableFuture.isDone() || completableFuture.isCancelled() || completableFuture.isCompletedExceptionally()) {
            executeRemainingFlow();
        }
    }

    private void processEventsAsynchronously(List<Object> events) {
        Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for (Object event : events) {
            Runnable runnable = () -> processEvent(event);
            executor.execute(runnable);
        }
    }

    private void processEvent(Object event) {
    
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void executeRemainingFlow() {

    }
```

Here I want to process list of events asynchronously and once the processing is done I want to implement remaining flow.
I tried to use CompletableFuture but the code inside the executer getting executed after executeRemainingFlow().

Comment: Consider using a CountDownLatch

Comment: How about using `.whenComplete` on the chain where you run `CompletableFuture.runAsync`?

Comment: What does `// waiting for all threads to get processed` stand for? If it stands for _nothing_ (i.e., if `processEvent()` really does nothing except wait) then there's no point to the `runAsync(...)` call. The only reason for your program to do some task T asynchronously is if there's some other task U that you want your program to do at the same time. If there is no other task U to perform while waiting for T to complete, then you might just as well _call_ the function that does task T instead of running it asynchronously.

Comment: Hi @SolomonSlow, this is just a demo program . In real program I have to return the count of successfully processed events and failed event and to get that count I want to wait till the execution of processEventsAsynchronously() get finished

Comment: Yes, but what _else_ does the main thread do while it is waiting? Are you going to put some code into the body of the "waiting for all threads to get processed" loop? What I'm saying is, It doesn't make any sense to call `runAsync(...)` if you don't have any code that you plan to put in that loop.

Answer (score 2):

Firs, get rid of the `CompletableFuture.runAsync(...)` call. It serves no purpose (see my comments on your question, above.) Then, use `Executors.awaitTermination()` to wait for all of the events to be processed.  That leaves you with this:

```java
private void processEvents(List<Object> events) {
    Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    for (Object event : events) {
        Runnable runnable = () -> processEvent(event);
        executor.execute(runnable);
    }

    // Tell the `executor` to shut down _after_ all of the tasks have completed.
    executor.shutdown();

    // Wait until the executor has finished shutting down.
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(9999, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.err.println("Uh Oh! **THIS** should never have happened:");
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }

    executeRemainingFlow();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer ... still have one question ... what if I call processEventsAsynchronously() multiple times? I want to run this method on each http request and therefore it will create multiple instance of executor  .... will this cause any memory issue

Comment: @AnkitKadam, If the program's going to call `processEvents()` more than one time, then it probably would be better to make the thread pool separately, and pass it in to that function as an argument. Creating and destroying thread pools won't cause "memory issues," but it's a costly operation, and there's no need to do it more than one time.